# Use stored procedure in SELECT. Can't use function because of TRY-CATCH

Tags: sql-server

I have a stored procedure that is a replacement for the `TRY_CONVERT` function in recent SQL Server versions, since the one I'm working in doesn't support it.

I need to do a query using that stored procedure that gets the rows that can't convert the given date to the given format, so basically the ones that return NULL when the conversion throws an error.

How can I use that stored procedure within a `SELECT` statement if I can't use a function? What other alternative do I have if it isn't possible? Thanks a lot!

EDIT: For clarity.

EDIT 2: Added an example.

This is an example of what I had for SQL 2014.

```
SELECT *
FROM TABLE T
WHERE TRY_CONVERT(DATE, T.DATE_1, 112) IS NULL
```

So I need to replace that `TRY_CONVERT` for a stored procedure or an user-defined function, like

```
SELECT *
FROM TABLE T
WHERE (SELECT CONVERTED_DATE FROM spConvertDate(DATE, T.DATE_1, 112)) IS NULL
```

Or something like that.

Comment: What? I don't understand what you are asking here at all

Comment: Sorry, you're right. I changed the question.

Comment: Perhaps you could share your SP code? And some details about what you are trying to do.

Comment: I think you should include an example of what you're trying to do...  such as a query that uses "try_convert()" and then how you wish you could replace it, even thought you know it doesn't work.  Also---  what version of SQL Server are you using now!

Comment: You cannot execute a stored procedure as part of a `SELECT` query. You *can* use UDFs, but not stored procs.

Comment: Took Sean and Mike suggestions and added an example.

Comment: @DavidGuevara - great :-)    So as Damien said, why not a UDF?  That's why I'm curious about your version of SQL Server.  What are you running?

Comment: I decided to use the solution I didn't want, a cursor. I couldn't use an UDF because of the `TRY-CATCH` statement when the `CONVERT` fails, so it returns `NULL` instead of failing. I'm using SQL Server 2008 R2, compatibility level 100.